# PHP syntax for postgresql Mixed-case table names

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a code below:

```
<?php
require "institution.php"
/* in this portion, query for database connection is executed, and  */

$institution= $_POST['institutionname'];

$sCampID =  'SELECT ins_id FROM institution where ins_name= '$institution' ';
$qcampID = pg_query($sCampID) or die("Error in query: $query." . pg_last_error($connection));
/* this portion outputs the ins_id */           
?>
```

My database before has no mixed-case table names, that's why when I run this query, it shows no error at all. But because I've changed my database for some reasons, and it contains now mixed-case table names, i have to change the code above into this one:

```
$sCampID =  'SELECT ins_id FROM "Institution" where ins_name= '$institution' ';
```

where the Institution has to be double quoted. The query returned parse error.
 When i removed this portion: where ins_name= '$institution', no error occured.

My question is how do I solve this problem where the table name which contains a mixed-case letter and a value stored in a variable ($institution in this case) will be combined in a single select statement?

Your answers and suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd advise you to read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php first -- it might also solve your problem.

Comment: okay, thank u so much.. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double quote instead

```
$sCampID =  "SELECT ins_id FROM \"Institution\" where ins_name= '$institution'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require "institution.php"
/* in this portion, query for database connection is executed, and  */

$institution= pg_escape_string($_POST['institutionname']);

$sQuery =  "SELECT ins_id FROM \"Institution\" where ins_name= '$institution'";
$qcampID = pg_query($sQuery) 
  or trigger_error("Error in query: $sQuery." . pg_last_error($connection));
/* this portion outputs the ins_id */           
?>
```

Note

- `pg_escape_string` as it ought to be used, not to protect from any injections but as just a part of the syntax.
- `trigger_error` which should be used instead of echo (and note proper variable name)
- and **double quotes** or your variable won't be extrapolated ( http://php.net/types.string for ref)
- and slashes at double quotes (same ref)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sCampID =  'SELECT ins_id FROM "Institution" where ins_name= \''.$institution.'\'';
```

String escaping.

As another commenter posted, read about SQL injection. What I have is not injection safe, consider using something with prepared statements, preferably PDO.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers (quote the table name, and use prepared statements to gain security and performance), read about [PG and tables case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774406/psycopg2-doesnt-like-table-names-that-start-with-a-lower-case-letter/2776308#2776308). If you have the option, you might consider to change your db schema, so that tables names (and columns and identifiers in general) are all lowercase. That would simplify a little your queries - (but require you to check all your actual quoted queries and unquote them).

Answer (score 0):

What happens if $institution contains the following string: ' or 1 = 1; --

That's what we call an SQL injection attack, and it's a super-easy way for hackers to steal your data -- and get you into big trouble with your customers.

You need to escape that string using pg_escape_string() before putting it into an SQL query.  I like to use sprintf() to build my queries:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT ins_id FROM \"Institution\" where ins_name= '%s'", pg_escape_string($conn, $institution));
```

In the above example, $conn is the connection identifier, created by calling pg_connect().