# Using a PreparedStatement to persist an array of Java Enums to an array of Postgres Enums

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Java Enum:

```
public enum Equipment { Hood, Blinkers, ToungTie, CheekPieces, Visor, EyeShield, None;}
```

and a corresponding Postgres enum:

```
CREATE TYPE equipment AS ENUM ('Hood', 'Blinkers', 'ToungTie', 'CheekPieces', 'Visor', 'EyeShield', 'None');
```

Within my database I have a table which has a column containing an array of "equipment" items:

```
CREATE TABLE "Entry" (
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq'::regclass),
    "date" character(10) NOT NULL,
    equipment equipment[]
);
```

And finally when I am running my application I have an array of the "Equipment" enums which I want to persist to the database using a Prepared Statement, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

```
StringBuffer sb =  new StringBuffer("insert into \"Entry\" ");
sb.append("( \"date\", \"equipment \" )");
sb.append(" values ( ?, ? )");
PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement(sb.toString());

ps.setString("2010-10-10");
ps.set???????????
```

Comment: Just to answer some of the comments below.  The example is only illustrative, not the exact code I'm using.  I know date is probably illegal as a column name, didn't really think while I was setting up the example :)

I will be normalizing, but wanted to if working wwith an enum array was possible.  Doesn't sound like it from below without a hack of some kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [this](http://xantorohara.blogspot.com/2009/07/jdbc-postgres-enums-and-prepared.html).

I'd suggest that your code look more like this:

```
    // A column named "date" is probably illegal and not very illustrative.  "date" is a keyword for most databases.
    // Building a string that never changes again and again is a waste of CPU and heap
    private static final String INSERT_SQL =  "insert into Entry(date,equipment) values(?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);

    // Use the type system properly.  Dates should be DATE type columns in a database.  Why string?    
    ps.setDate(entryDate);

    // You shouldn't want to insert an array of values; that's not normalized.
    ps.setString(equipmentEnumValue.name());
```

Comment: Psst, `name()`, not `getName()`. And on retrieval, use `Enum#valueOf(String)` on the outcome of `ResultSet#getString()`. +1 for normalizing.

Comment: I had already read that article duffymo, works perfectly for single enum entries, but not for arrays.  As you suggest I should normalize, but was just interested to know if the arrays were possible.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is about how to use arrays.  For those of us who have a legitimate use for them, this answer is not useful 

Comment: Nine years ago it was accepted.  If you have a better one, please post it.  If not, go find another way to burnish your rep here besides posting comments on decade old answers.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact problem, and could not find a good solution.

The solution I ended up settling on was to insert as an array of String:

```
conn.createArrayOf("varchar", elements.toArray());
```

and to have an assignment cast in the DB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_meal_array(src_str character varying[]) RETURNS meal_type[] AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN src_str::text[]::meal_type[];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP CAST IF EXISTS (character varying[] as meal_type[]);
CREATE CAST (character varying[] AS meal_type[]) WITH FUNCTION cast_meal_array(character varying[]) AS assignment;
```

I was not happy with this solution, but it does work and does not require any particular JDBC wizardry.

Comment: Note that you could also probably just have the cast on your prepared statement, if you're willing to do it for every statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do two non standards things in plain JDBC: enums and arrays. None of them is  very straightforward - though both can be done. But I advise against both: I prefer to use ad-hoc-enums (just integers in some parametric table), and avoid arrays inside the database, except in very special cases. If you insist, attack one problem at a time.

BTW, you have two other issues: identifiers (tables and column names) with mixed cases (that must be quoted to avoid postgresql folding to lower case), and a column with a reserved sql word (date) as name.  This is not bad, but it certainly does not make your developer life easier...
And more BTW: beware of that  space after `\"equipment \"`

Comment: First time using Postgres, so thanks for the info about case.  Was wondering why I needed the quotes

Comment: @McGin : some more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774406/psycopg2-doesnt-like-table-names-that-start-with-a-lower-case-letter/2776308#2776308