# Error message when using INSERT INTO

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Here is a Student table I coded in postgreSQL (an excerpt):

```
CREATE TABLE "Student"
(
  ucas_no integer NOT NULL,
  student_name character(30) NOT NULL,
  current_qualification character(30),
  degree_of_interest character(30),
  date_of_birth date NOT NULL,
  street_address character(30) NOT NULL,
  city character(30) NOT NULL,
  post_code character(10) NOT NULL,
  country character(20) NOT NULL,
  phone_no character(15) NOT NULL,
  gender character(6) NOT NULL,
  user_name character(15) NOT NULL,
  "password" character(30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_ucas_no PRIMARY KEY (ucas_no),
  CONSTRAINT ten_digits_only CHECK (length(ucas_no::character(1)) >= 10 OR length(ucas_no::character(1)) <= 10)
)
```

Now i'm using the query tool feature of pgAdmin to insert data into the table. Here's the INSERT INTO code...

```
INSERT INTO Student
VALUES
('912463857', 'Jon Smith', 'A-Level', 'BSc(Hons) Computer Science', '10/06/1990', '50 Denchworth Road', 'LONDON', 'OBN 244', 'England', '02077334444', 'Male', 'jonsmi', '123456');
```

The problem I'm having is, i'm getting an error message saying the Student table does not exist, when it's clearly in my databse. Here's the error message:

```
ERROR:  relation "student" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO Student (ucas_no, student_name, current_qualific...
                    ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "student" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 13
```

Anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Also in the INSERT INTO code, does it matter I wrap the data with a single quote or not? I see some code have single quotes and others don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have created a table `"Student"` and you are trying to insert into a table called `Student` which are different

try this

```
INSERT INTO "Student" VALUES('912463857', 'Jon Smith', 'A-Level', 'BSc(Hons) Computer Science', '10/06/1990', '50 Denchworth Road', 'LONDON', 'OBN 244', 'England', '02077334444', 'Male', 'jonsmi', '123456');
```

This will work

please go through this about qoutes [omitting-the-double-quote-to-do-query-on-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331504/omitting-the-double-quote-to-do-query-on-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you PresleyDias. It works now. Also thanks for the link, some good info in there.

Answer (score 3):

Look for "quoted identifier" in ["4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

As for your second question (don't comment on your questions, edit them if related, create new if not) - read the whole ["Chapter 4. SQL Syntax"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax.html) of the manual, but the bare minimum is ["4.1.2. Constants"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at it and get back to you if I have any problems.