# mysql double-quoted table names

Tags: mysql, double-quotes

I'm doing a mysql query like:

```
Select * from "User";
```

and it returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"User"' at line 1

The error has something to do with the double-quotes `"`, can I keep the select statement as is, and make mysql cope with the double quotes?

Comment: The code is not mine, the application is already built and this convention may be used all over the application

Comment: Double-quotes are standard ANSI delimiters for identifiers.  What is your sql_mode?  Is there a table named User, user, USER or similar?  What is the case sensitivity of the server's operating system?

Comment: the sql_mode was :
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
and then i executed "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ANSI';" and it then became:
REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ANSI

Comment: when running "select * form user" it executes correctly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote):

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;
```

Personally when I tested, I had to do it like this:

```
SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;
```

I don't think there's any other way.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes
>
> #### ANSI_QUOTES
>
> Treat “"” as an identifier quote character (like the “`” quote
> character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use “`”
> to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled,
> you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings,
> because it is interpreted as an identifier.

Comment: it worked !!!
but what is the difference between GLOBAL SQL_MODE and just SQL_MODE ??

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest - SQL is not a strong point for me. Both queries work for me, but the `GLOBAL` one did not seem to do anything.

Comment: `SET SESSION SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;` is another way to do it that might make more sense. See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html As I said, I'm no pro at SQL so you might want to research any side effects, caveats, etc.