# why sql give me error "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

Today I got error Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in my yii app while updating data . then i come to know that my sql database table column contains name with "-" symbol i.e "table-post" etc .

Then i changed "-" with "_" and everything is working .

This is the query snippet (I replaced the "-" with "_")

```
/* percentage  losses  senser*/
    $attributes['totlcommloss_sensor']  = $_POST['totlcommloss_sensor'];
    $attributes['asp_hour_sensor']= $_POST['asp-hour_sensor'];
    $attributes['asp_daily_sensor'] = $_POST['asp-daily_sensor'];
    $attributes['asp_weekly_sensor']= $_POST['asp-weekly_sensor'];
    $attributes['asp_monthly_sensor'] = $_POST['asp-monthly_sensor'];
    $attributes['asp_5_day_senser']= $_POST['asp_5_day_senser'];

    /* cost losses */
    //$attributes['costlosshourly'] = $_POST['acs-hourly'];

    if (0 != intval($user['id'])) {         
        $command->update('alarm_settings', $attributes, 'id=:id', array(':id' => intval($user['id'])));
            } 
    else {
        $NumberOfRowsEffected = $command->insert('alarm_settings', $attributes);
         }
```

Can some one explain why this example shows error? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query which failed?

Comment: Also add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, the '-' in your table name will be seen as a calculation and not as part of the actual table name. The reason behind this is that MySQL can only give one function to a character/word, and does not know which one you actually want to use at that particular spot in your query.

In MySQL a lot of these **special characters or reserved words** exist. Every time you use one of those, **backticks** have to be used.

Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

[According to MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), you do not need to quote (backtick) identifiers using the following character set:

> ASCII: `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]` (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

You can use characters beyond that set as table or column identifiers, including whitespace for example, but then you *must* quote (backtick) them.

In your case using `table-post` (backticks!) instead of table-post should work

Comment: NOTE: If MySQL `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`, then identifiers can be enclosed in double quotes instead of backticks.

Comment: This answer deserves the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Based on mysql documentation on [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)
Only following characters are permitted as non quoted identifiers.

> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

`-` ANSI(45) isn't allowed as a valid identifier unless it is quoted with backticks (``) or double quotes("") which are ANSI SQL compatible with [`ANSI_QUOTES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884854/mysql-double-quoted-table-names)

> Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>
> ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F