# Postgres Syntax requiring extra ' ' and "" around things

Tags: postgresql

So I am reading tutorial online and I am having a weird issue with my database when doing normal queries. So I see the following does not work:

```
select * from DBS
ERROR:  relation "dbs" does not exist
```

but This works:

```
select * from "DBS"
```

When I do this it fails:

```
select name from "DBS" 
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
```

but this works but doesnt actually return the correct information (it just has name for every row:

```
select 'name' from "DBS"

name
name
name
```

Is there some setting on Postgres causing this to happen? 
Postgres 9.4.5 (On RDS).

```
select 'NAME' from "DBS";
 ?column?
----------
 NAME
 NAME
 NAME
(3 rows)
```

When I look at select * from "DBS";

```
    NAME
----------
    default
    matt
    matt2
```

Comment: What is the result of `select "name" from "DBS"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the quotes around the table identifier, because the table uses capital letters and was created using quotes.

[postgres has some distinctive behavior re: quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331504/omitting-the-double-quote-to-do-query-on-postgresql)

```
select 'name' from "DBS"
```

You are simply selecting the string literal 'name' once for each row in your table.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres is a little unique in that it folds everything to lowercase unless you use " quotes. I suspect you created your database using pgadmin. If you create a database in pgadmin using UPPER case it will create it with UPPER case and then you will be required to use " around the name to access it. Candidly I'd rename the db to lower case and get rid of the quotes, your life will be a lot easier.