# Sqlalchemy + Firebird: How to remove quotation marks

Tags: sqlalchemy, firebird

I am new to SqlAlchemy and Firebird DB.

I can directly create a table using DBeaver:

```sql
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE (
    COLUMN1 FLOAT,
    COLUMN2 FLOAT
);
```

but if I try to do the same using pyndas+sqlalchemy I get an error:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd


engine = sa.create_engine(r'firebird+fdb://user:pwd@localhost:3050/c:\XXX.FDB', echo=False)
df = pd.DataFrame({"COLUMN1":[], "COLUMN2":[]})
df.to_sql(name="NEWTABLE", con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False, method=None)
```

```
DatabaseError: (fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError) ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -817\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -817\n- Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1', -817, 335544569)
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE "NEWTABLE" (
    COLUMN1 FLOAT, 
    COLUMN2 FLOAT
)
```

**The problem is due to the quotation marks `"..."` in `to_sql` query.**

1. How to tell sqlalchemy not to use quotation marks to be compatible with Firebird (dialect 1)?

as an alternative:

2. Instead of executing the query immediately, is it possible to produce the query string only from `to_sql` and execute it later with `result = engine.execute(query)`? This would give the possibility to fix these incompatibilities before execution.

Comment: Why are you using a dialect 1 database? Is this a new project or a legacy project? Dialect 1 (which doesn't support quoted object names, and where double quotes delimit a string instead) was deprecated **20 years ago** in favor of dialect 3 (which supports quoted object names, and strings are delimited by single quotes). Using dialect 1 with modern tools which expect reasonable standard SQL behavior  is hard. If this is a new project, I'd strongly recommend switching to a dialect 3 database.

Comment: Alas, yes: it is a legacy project, no way to use something less archaic...

Comment: I'd recommend migrating the database to dialect 3, unless that is really not an option.

Comment: Alas it isn't an option. A closed app is based on this database, and it is not possible to migrate it.

Comment: @AlexPoca you might try to override a dialect connection-wise, using parameter: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/driver_manuals/odbc/html/fbodbc205-conn-params.html // Granted, i do not remember exactly what gets overriden and what not, it is not a mode supported, and Vlad Khorsun usually gets very annoyed at "lame questions" about this. But as a short term solution it erhaps might work. Or maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a possible solution reading [Get rid of double quotation marks with SQLalchemy for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070409/get-rid-of-double-quotation-marks-with-sqlalchemy-for-postgresql): **if the table name is uppercase, it is automatically surrounded by quotation marks**.

**Experimentally I see that the same apply to Firebird**, even if I didn't find any proper reference to this issue but only [something apparently unrelated](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq76/)

A change to

```
df.to_sql(name="newtable", ...)
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created models:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

base = declarative_base()

class Base(base):
    __abstract__ = True
    __table_args__ = {'quote':False}
    

db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)


class Newtable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'NEWTABLE '
    column1 = db.Column('COLUMN1', db.Float, quote=False)
    column2 = db.Column('COLUMN2', db.Float, quote=False)
```