# Avoid pandas.to_sql writes into table with double quotes (PostgreSQL database)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to export my dataframe to sql database (Postgres).

**I created the table as following:**

```
CREATE TABLE dataops.OUTPUT
(
    ID_TAIL CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_MODEL CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_FIN CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_GROUP_FIN CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ID_COMPONENT CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DT_OPERATION TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    DT_EXECUTION TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FT_VALUE_SENSOR FLOAT NOT NULL,
    DT_LOAD TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

**And I want to write this dataframe into that sql table:**

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgres://root:1234@localhost:5432/postgres")
data = [['ID_1',  'A4_DOOUE_ADM001',  '1201MJ52',  'PATH_1',  'LATCHED1AFT',
         '2016-06-22 19:10:25',  '2020-11-12 17:20:33.616016',  2.9,  '2020-11-12 17:54:06.340735']]

output_df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["id_tail", "id_model", "id_fin", "id_group_fin", "id_component", "dt_operation",
                                             "dt_execution", "ft_value_sensor", "dt_load"])
```

But, when I run the command to write into database `output_df.to_sql` I realize that a new table "OUTPUT", with double qupotes has been created with the data inserted.

```
output_df.to_sql(cfg.table_names["output_rep27"], conn, cfg.db_parameters["schema"], if_exists='append',index=False)
```

**This is what I see in my DDBB:**
[image]

**But the same table without quotes is empty:**
[image]

When you purposely try to insert the table wrong (changing a column name for example) you see that pandas is inserting with double quotes because the error:
[image]

How to avoid pandas inserts with double quotes for the table?

Comment: Force the table name to lower case `cfg.table_names["output_rep27"].lower()`. That would not turn off the double quoting, but would result in  all lower case table names.

Comment: May be you misunderstood, the problem is not uppercase vs lowercase, the problem is trying to write with double quotes, I have tried to modify the font code but I have failed until the moment

Answer (score 0):

Short version Pandas is double quoting identifiers which is fairly standard. When that happens with upper case identifier you have to double quote from then on when using it. Using it unquoted will fold the name to lower case and you won't find the table. For more information on this, see [Identifier Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). You have three choices, do as I suggested in comment and force name to lower case, always double quote identifiers when using them or modify Panda source code to not double quote.

Comment: Do you know where the double quotes are added?

Comment: No and I would argue strongly against modifying the source for a couple of reasons. 1) You will be forever have to be doing that. 2) It is probably going to create a new issue. Namely that when you do `CREATE TABLE SOME_UPPER_CASE_NAME` the name will become `some_upper_case_name`. Without the quoting it will get case folded down. Read the link I posted in my answer, it should make things clearer.

Comment: The problem is not about pandas but sqlalchemy, that's the code I modified, it worked.

Comment: Except now you won't have an upper/mixed case table name but an all lower case one. And you have lost the ability to have upper/mixed case names.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088127) is the accepted answer for it

We need to set the dataframe column into lower case before we send it to PostgreSQL, and set a lower cased table name for the table, so we don't need to add double quotes when we select the table or columns

*EDIT : I found out that whitespace also force to_sql function from pandas to write the table or column name using double quotes in PostgreSQL, so if you wanna make the table or column name double-quotes-free, change the whitespaces into non-whitespace characters or just delete the whitespaces from the table name or column name

this is the example from my own case:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
ws = re.compile("\s+")

# lower the case, strip leading and trailing white space,
# and substitute the whitespace between words with underscore
df.columns = [ws.sub("_", i.lower().strip()) for i in df.columns]

my_db_name = 'postgresql://postgres:my_password@localhost:5432/db_name' 
engine = create_engine(my_db_name) 
df.to_sql('lowercase_table_name', engine) #use lower cased table name
```

Comment: No, it should work even with uppercase, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @Henry Navarro I don't really get the point from your comment (maybe you can explain your comment so I can response properly),

but **this solution will makes the resulting table name and column name clean (selecting without using double quotes) and case insensitive**, so you can select your resulting table and columns with lower, upper or mixed letter case as long as the letter match the columns or the table name

Comment: Basically the solution is to just set everything to lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

this line of code worked for me

```
appended_data.columns = map(str.lower, df2.columns)
appended_data.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, 
              schema='public', index=False, if_exists='append',method='multi')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use large letters in pandas in order to get names without quotes in SQL table.
Use this code on your df.

```
 df.columns.str.upper()
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't found a "good" solution, so what I did was to create my own function to insert the values:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgres://root:1234@localhost:5432/postgres")
data = [['ID_1',  'A4_DOOUE_ADM001',  '1201MJ52',  'PATH_1',  'LATCHED1AFT',
         '2016-06-22 19:10:25',  '2020-11-12 17:20:33.616016',  2.9,  '2020-11-12 17:54:06.340735']]

output_df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["id_tail", "id_model", "id_fin", "id_group_fin", "id_component", "dt_operation",
                                             "dt_execution", "ft_value_sensor", "dt_load"])
    
def to_sql(output_df,table_name,conn,schema):
        my_query = 'INSERT INTO '+schema+'.'+table_name+' ('+", ".join(list(output_df.columns))+') \
                    VALUES ('+ ", ".join(np.repeat('%s',output_df.shape[1]).tolist()) +');'
        record_to_insert = output_df.applymap(str).values.tolist()
        conn.execute(my_query,record_to_insert)

to_sql(output_df,table_name,conn,schema)
```

I hope it is useful for somebody

Comment: Hi, i tried to run your function instead of .to_sql(), but to throws an error LINE 1: INSERT INTO public.test_database (kind,collectionName,trackN.... However, I am running without declaring schema.

Comment: Were you able to find any working solutions?

Comment: @PatrickHellman what do you mean with "working solutions"? I cannot see your database so I don't know exactly what you mean. In my case this function worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For those, who is still looking for the answer.

Instead of writing

```
output_df.to_sql(name='some_schema.some_table', con=conn)
```

you should put schema into corresponding to_sql() parameter

```
output_df.to_sql(name='some_table', schema='some_schema', con=conn)
```

Otherwise 'some_schema.some_table' will be considered as single table name and enquoted.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure if you understood the question