# Make pandas.to_sql to create tables with lowercase table name in SAP HANA database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, hana, pandas-to-sql

Simple, i just want to create lowercase tables with pandas.to_sql. Tried the following:

```
df.to_sql(name=hdb_table_name.lower(), schema="SCHEMA_NAME", con=hdb_connection, index=True, if_exists='replace')
```

Only when hdb_table_name includes whitespaces, it actually creates lowercase (or case sensitive) tables in HANA. But this does not sound like a sufficient workaround to have a whole database based on whitespace tables names.

Why not capital letters? Unfortunately the above code will throw the following error if the table already exists and has an uppercase name:

> Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in
> Engine(HANA_ADDRESS) schema 'SCHEMA_NAME': (TABLE_NAME_UPPERCASE)

Found related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808427/avoid-pandas-to-sql-writes-into-table-with-double-quotes-postgresql-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070409/get-rid-of-double-quotation-marks-with-sqlalchemy-for-postgresql/48088127#48088127), but not on this specific behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

in SAP Hana

- At the time of table creation, the case of a column name is not preserved unless the column name is quoted. Snowflake stores unquoted column names in uppercase.
- The column names in a select statement are not case sensitive unless quoted.
- Equal (=) and Not Equal (!=) in a where clause are case sensitive.

[image: 1]

Comment: This behavior is exactly the problem. I assume that the df.to_sql(...) function does not put quotation marks around the name parameter in the query sent to the hanaDB. The only way i found was to put a space in the name, but as mentioned, i don't find this a long-term solution.

Comment: @sony give an example of what you have in database and what df_tosql gives you and what you need.and how do you run that query , if you are using sqlalchemy ( which is what pandas use) we might find a solution

Comment: i created an issue on the pandas repository, as i think i might found the underlying issue. There is also a more detailed explanation. You can check it out, maybe you'll find a fix :). https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45474

Comment: @sony what happens if you pass tablename when you call to_sql like this : `df.to_sql(name='"tablename"' ,...` . send table name with quotation

Comment: this creates a table named  "tablename", so including the quotation marks

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the [Python Machine Learning Client for SAP HANA](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/) (available on PyPI). It offers the [HANA Dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html), which behaves similar to a Pandas Dataframe, but pushes operations to the database instead of keeping the data on the client.

For simply creating a table on HANA from a given Pandas Dataframe, you can use function [create_dataframe_from_pandas()](https://help.sap.com/doc/1d0ebfe5e8dd44d09606814d83308d4b/2.0.06/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.create_dataframe_from_pandas).

I haven't tested it with your specific example, but it's worth a try checking if it treats the double quotes more consequently.