# Insert into table doesn't go in Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

i have created a page to insert element into a database in php.
At the beggining i start use with mySQL, and it works perfectly. Then I'm migrate to Postgres and so i had some problems.
I change my code and i don't receive erros,but when i'm trying to insert my elements into the db, this remains empty.

this the structure of my table **Prenotazione**

```
CREATE TABLE public."Prenotazione"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Prenotazione_id_seq"'::regclass),
  nominativo character(20),
  email character(20),
  oggetto character(200),
  nominativoi character(200),
  nominativoe character(200),
  emaili character(200),
  emaile character(200),
  data date,
  orario_inizio time without time zone,
  orario_fine time without time zone,
  stanza integer
)
```

this is my **index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
                        <b>&ensp;Richiedente Conferenza:</b><br><br>
                        &ensp;Nominativo:<br>&ensp;<input type="text" name="nominativo" placeholder="Nome Cognome" size="20"><br>
                        &ensp;Email: <br> &ensp;<input type="email" name="email" size="20" placeholder="email"><br>
                        &ensp;Oggetto Conferenza:<br>&ensp;<textarea name="oggetto" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="Specificare oggetto Videoconferenza"></textarea><br>
                        &ensp;Data: <br>&ensp;<input  type="date" name="data"  ><br>
                        &ensp;Orario Inizio: <br>&ensp;<input type="time" name="orario_inizio" min="09:30:00" max="16:30:00" ><br>
                        &ensp;Orario Fine: <br>&ensp;<input type="time" name="orario_fine" min="10:00:00" max="18:30:00"><br>

                        <br>
                        <b>&ensp;Partecipanti Interni </b>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                <div id="interni">
                    <div id="first">
                        &ensp;Nominativo:<br>&ensp;<textarea name="nominativoi" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Nome Cognome;"  ></textarea><br>
                        &ensp;Email:<br>&ensp; <textarea  name="emaili" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Inserire Email"></textarea><br> 
                      <br>
                      <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <b>&ensp;Partecipanti Esterni </b>
                <div id="esterni">
                    <div id="first">
                               &ensp;Nominativo:<br>&ensp;<textarea name="nominativoe" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Nome Cognome;" ></textarea><br>
                                &ensp;Email:<br>&ensp;<textarea  name="emaile" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Inserire Email"></textarea><br> 
                      <br>
                    &ensp;&ensp;<input type="submit" value="Invia" > 
                        </form>
```

And finally the **input.php**

```
$checkdata = "SELECT count(*) as prenotato
  FROM Prenotazione
 WHERE data='$data'
   AND NOT ('$newTimeEnd' < orario_inizio OR orario_fine < '$orario_inizio')";

$querycheck = $dbh->prepare($checkdata);
$querycheck->execute();
$prenotato = $querycheck->fetch()[0];
var_dump($prenotato);
if ($prenotato == 0 AND $stanza == 0 ) { 

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$newTimeEnd','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',1)";
    var_dump($query1);
    $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $result1->execute();
    $rex = 1;
}
else if ($prenotato == 1){
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza) VALUES ('$nominativo','$email','$data','$orario_inizio','$orario_fine','$oggetto','$nominativoi','$emaili','$nominativoe','$emaile',2)";
    $result1 = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $result1->execute();
    $rex = 1;
}
```

I posted the part that are interesting to the problem.
Thanks

The result of var_dump is :

> NULL string(269) "INSERT INTO Prenotazione
>   (nominativo,email,data,orario_inizio,orario_fine,oggetto,nominativoi,emaili,nominativoe,emaile,stanza)
>   VALUES
>   ('username','email@email.com','2018-10-03','09:30','12:30','object','username1','email1@email1.com','username2','email2@email2.com',1)"

Comment: Maybe the statement causes an error. Did you check?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how can i check ? The stranger thing is that in mysql the code goes well.

Comment: I have try the only insert into database and he doesn't work. I tried to print the variables like var_dump($nominativo) and it takes this. So i don't understand where is the problem

Comment: Check if `execute` returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: I try and it prints "Notice: Undefined variable: params in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PhpProject1/inputs.php on line 41
It failed!"! How can i do now???

Comment: I used this code: $try = $querycheck->execute($params);

if ($try) {
   echo 'It worked!';
} else {
   echo 'It failed!';
}

Comment: Well the failure you're getting now is to do with your php code, but as it was not part of the code posted above (there's no `params` variable) it's difficult to say...

Comment: @eurotrash oh my fault! I copied the code from a tutorial and i forget to change $params variable. How can i do to see if execute is true or false?

Comment: Not sure, I only know postgres not php. If you have access to your postgres server you can check the log file to see if there was any error.

Comment: Ok :( i didn't find nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your table name in double quotes. Don't use double quotes, or use them in every request.

You can verify your code here:

http://rextester.com/VIEH75483

Also, see more: [Omitting the double quote to do query on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331504/omitting-the-double-quote-to-do-query-on-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i create new table without "" but the insert doesn't go :(