# alembic not generating tables in schema

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

I have a docker setup consisting of three containers.
A) uvicorn/fastAPI app
B) mongoDB
C) Postgres DB

All three working. This is a problem with alembic, hosted in container A with the rest of my app, making changes to postgres in container C.

I have a DatabaseSession class that connects to the DB.
I can connect just fine and run commands. It does seem to be responding.
Here is the connect method within that class:

```
def _connect_db(self, db_schema_override: str = None):
        schema = self.schema if not db_schema_override else db_schema_override
        try:
            engine = create_engine(
                self.db_url, connect_args={"options": "-csearch_path={}".format(schema)}
            )
            SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
            session = SessionLocal()
            metadata = MetaData()
            metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
            metadata.create_all(engine)
            return engine, session
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            raise
```

here is my alembic migrations file

```
def upgrade_db(db_schema: str, revision: str = "head") -> None:
    db = DatabaseSession(db_schema)
    db.db_data.maintenance_mode = True
    db.db_data.save()
    _config = config.Config("path/to/file/alembic.ini")
    _config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", db.db_url)
    with db.engine.begin() as cnxn:
        _config.attributes["connection"] = cnxn
        _config.attributes["schema"] = db_schema.lower()
        command.upgrade(_config, revision)
        db.db_data.maintenance_mode = False
        db.db_data.save()
```

here is my alembic env.py file run_migrations_online function:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )
    db_schema = config.attributes.get("schema", "public")

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(text(f'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "{db_schema}"'))
        connection.execute(text(f"SET search_path TO '{db_schema}'"))
        connection.dialect.default_schema_name = db_schema

        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            include_schemas=True,
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

as you can see, Im utilizing schemas within each database to further seperate concerns.
Im basically using mongodb to store DB records including database name and schema.
Ive checked permissions on postgres, i can log into postgres and run commands as the same user and create tables.

I can access postgres from python using my DatabaseSession class and run commands as that same user. But I cannot seem to create anything.

When i run a 'create table' command using my DatabaseSession class from python interpreter, it registers the command was sent.
But if i run \dt or anything in the psql CLI in another window, no changes show up.
If i try to rerun the 'create table' command using the DatabaseSession class again, itll this time say this table already exists.

Its like its not committing the command. If i kill the session, or do a rollback, I can rerun the command just fine once.
Am i supposed to be commiting this?

ive also tried just running alembic upgrade head. Same issue.
It says it ran all the migrations just fine. no errors. but no changes persist in the DB.

additionally, Alembic does not appear to be creating the versions table where it houses the migration ID.

ive done this EXACT same setup in the past (earlier version of sqlalchemy). Im not exactly sure whats so different now that i cant seem to get this work.

#### Summary

- using database/schema setup
- can connect and run commands as user within schema via CLI
- can connect and run commands from python. but nothing persists
- no alembic version table exists within my database/schema

any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Can you try dropping the quotes around the `db_schema` in `CREATE SCHEMA` and `SET search_path `?  Seems like that might cause an inconsistency.

Comment: Maybe related here, not sure:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331504/omitting-the-double-quote-to-do-query-on-postgresql

Comment: Or I guess if you NEED to quote the schema I think you need to tell sqlalchemy to quote it throughout and it should be one or the other.   Looks like you apply `.lower()` earlier, are the schemas mixed case?

Comment: So I tried with and without quotes. Doesnt seem to be the issue. 
Also, to confirm for at least testing this, I am 100% certain that the variables are being stored and called lower case.

Comment: Sorry, just for completeness did you list the schemas and make sure there are not duplicates?  For example `CREATE SCHEMA MySchema` and `CREATE SCHEMA "MySchema"` will create two different schemas on my postgresql machine, `myschema` and `"MySchema"` respectively.

Comment: Maybe you could simplify the example a bit so someone could replicate it.  What version of SqlAlchemy are you using?

Comment: Nevermind about example, I can just copy your `env.py` code into my own alembic `env.py`.

Comment: Hey. Appreciate the responses. Im working on this in my spare time currently. forgive the long silence. 
version of sqlalchemy im using: 2.0.15. And yea the important bit is the env.py file. The rest is just in case somethings wrong with the way Im connecting otherwise. But my tests all seem fine there. So i think its something with the way the context is setup in the env..py file. but I havent successfuly made it work yet.

Comment: I put a comment on my answer but if you look here Alembic doc's use commit and that seems to fix your problem: [rudimental-schema-level-multi-tenancy-for-postgresql-databases](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#rudimental-schema-level-multi-tenancy-for-postgresql-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `'event'` example below appears to be working but you're right.  Your example just seems to rollback when you set `echo=True` on the engine.

Your example doesn't seem to work in `SqlAlchemy>=2` only in `SqlAlchemy<2`.

After thinking about this it seems if you add
`connection.commit()` after you set the `dialect.default_schema_name = db_schema` then your code does seem to work in sqlalchemy 2.

I created a new alembic project, set the sqlalchemy url to a test postgresql db.

Then I:

1. rm any versions
2. drop the db
3. create the db
4. run `alembic revision --autogenerate`
5. run `alembic upgrade head`

Your version seems to rollback.

I lifted the `@event` from
[setting-alternate-search-paths-on-connect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#setting-alternate-search-paths-on-connect).

```py
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.attributes['schema'] = 'myschema'

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer

metadata = MetaData()
users_t = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
)

target_metadata = metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
        echo=True,
    )
    db_schema = config.attributes.get("schema", "public")

    # Toggle this between 'event' and 'inline'
    schema_strategy = 'inline'

    if schema_strategy == 'event':
        from sqlalchemy import event
        @event.listens_for(connectable, "connect", insert=True)
        def set_search_path(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
            existing_autocommit = dbapi_connection.autocommit
            dbapi_connection.autocommit = True
            cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {db_schema}')
            cursor.execute(f"SET SESSION search_path='{db_schema}'")
            cursor.close()
            dbapi_connection.autocommit = existing_autocommit

    with connectable.connect() as connection:

        if schema_strategy == 'inline':
            connection.execute(text(f'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "{db_schema}"'))
            connection.execute(text(f"SET search_path TO '{db_schema}'"))
            connection.dialect.default_schema_name = db_schema

        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata,
            include_schemas=True,
        )
        with context.begin_transaction() as trans:
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Comment: In this example alembic is also calling `commit()`: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#rudimental-schema-level-multi-tenancy-for-postgresql-databases

Comment: This is working for you? very interesting. It is not working for me. When I copy paste what you have here into my env.py file, it acts the same as this question is reporting. hmm.. I also tried the link you sent and added the commit. still no go. But it was now able to generate the alembic_version table. but no other tables were generated despite the sql commands appearing to go through.

Comment: NVM my last comment. This DID work. Turns out last night I created a new starting revision file with too many schema settings. So every sql command generated was generated with schema.table_name. So that was throwing my for a loop. Adding the commit did work. thank you!