# Test Container Initialize Mongo Db With Insert Document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, java-11, testcontainers

I am using testContanier for unit and integration tests.

I need to initialize mongo db with insert document. How can I initialize mongo db before spring boot is runnig ?

```
@BeforeAll
public static void startAndInitializeContainer(){
 final MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10"))

mongoDBContainer.start();
}
```

I have @PostConstruct annotation therefore I need to initialize mongodb under the @BeforeAll annotation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/73029378/2203890 ?

Comment: @EddúMeléndez yes ı checked it but, ı can not use additional maven dependency.

Comment: Have you tried using spring test listeners to inseet the docs before the test method runs https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testexecutionlistener

Comment: You can use any Java code you would normally use to add data to MongoDB, there is nothing Testcontainers specific about this (nor should be).

Comment: @KevinWittek I need to insert before spring boot application run.

Comment: I think you need to update your question regarding what do you really need and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @GhostDede than you have to use a MongoDB client that you construct independent from SpringBoot, e.g., see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/insertOne/. However, it is also unclear why you need the data before the SpringBootContext is initialized.