Load testing with stateful data [POST http request]
I'm trying to understand how load testing can be done on a POST HTTP Request when the data are stateful.
For clarity, here's an example:
When a POST HTTP request is fired, the data will changed from A -> B. The same data (which is now "B") cannot be fired, because the business logic only accepts "A".
Ideas I could think of...
What are the techniques to handle such testing?

Creating a huge numbers of "A" records in database for this purpose. (I however think this is not possible, since we are trying to do load testing, I may fire more APIs than the number of records I attempt to create)
Script it. Perform a pre-hook/post-hook by resetting the same data to original state before the next call. (I have a concern here, will pre/post hook take extra time to reset it, which cause the load test result metrics inaccurate?)


Sounds like you just want unit testing that validate A can change to B, and any state that's currently B returns invalid request response... Unclear why that would need load tested unless B is frequently reset to A. In other words, you'd only be able to execute one request that's expected to do anything, A->B

@OneCricketeer, validating data is B is not my intention. I'm only providing a very simply example to illustrate the stateful data. The goal here is the really load testing with say for example 1000 or more A records within X minutes with Y number of users.

Regarding your database question, try Testcontainers https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460428/2308683

Repeatability is one of the most important features of the test.
Your "Script it" approach will lead to gaps between requests and extra load to the system (i.e. you will need to fire at least one extra request to "revert" the state)
Well-behaved test should leave the system at exactly the same stage as before test. The fastest and easiest option is taking a database dump with as many records in A state as needed, running your test and then restoring the dump so the system under test would be in an initial state.
If it's not possible you could do in on load testing tool level, for example Apache JMeter provides:

setUp Thread Group - to prepare the system under test, create test data, test users, etc
tearDown Thread Group - to revert any changes made


Looks like, setting up the data manually is the only option? At least for one time.
